# mxd.SaveACopy fails to save file using Python script

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.4, python-script-tool, save

I have been struggling to build a model using ModelBuilder and Python scripts. At the end of the model, I would like to write a script which saves the MXD file using the actual current time of the process.
Hence, I have used the following script, but it does not work, displaying "failed to save document" error.

```
# Import arcpy and datetime modules
import arcpy
import datetime

#Setting variables
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
now = datetime.datetime.now()
TIME = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
mxdName = "Analysis" + str(TIME)+ ".mxd"

#saving Script
mxd.saveACopy(%GDBpath% + mxdName)
```

So, I decided to simplify the script. The result is as followed:

```
# Import arcpy and datetime modules
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as map

#Setting Variables
mxdName = "Analysis" + ".mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\SOHCO\Desktop\New folder" + mxdName)
```

**But I still receive "failed to save the document" error.**

Could anyone help me out?

Note: The %GDPpath% (from the first script) refers to a parse path tool in order to apply the directory that the user defines for the tool. (the image is attached at the end of the question)

[image]

picture of the error:

[image]

Comment: Your path+filename is `r"C:\Users\SOHCO\Desktop\New folderAnalysis.mxd"`, =missing a backslash so it is invalid. Replace line with `mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\SOHCO\Desktop\New folder",mxdName))` and you also need `import os`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a file or folder name with ":" characters - it's a [reserved character](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#file-and-directory-names).

And in your 2nd snippet, you're trying to create `r"C:\Users\SOHCO\Desktop\New folderAnalysis_etc.mxd"`, i.e you're missing the last `\`.

Try the following instead:

```
# Import arcpy, os and datetime modules
import arcpy
import os
import datetime

#Setting variables
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
now = datetime.datetime.now()
TIME = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")  # <== Note change from "%H:%M:%S" to "%H-%M-%S"

gdbPath = r"C:\Users\SOHCO\Desktop\New folder"
mxdName = "Analysis_{}.mxd".format(TIME)  # string formatting doesn't make any difference, I just prefer it to + concatenation

#saving Script
mxd.saveACopy(os.path.join(gdbPath, mxdName))
```